# How to import a module given the full path of the module in python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I load a Python module given its full path? Note that the file can be anywhere in the file system, as it is a configuration option.
i am using python 3.5 in ubutnu , my code so far is :

Create python module test.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("test/lib/")
from tes1 import Client1
from tes2 import Client2
import tes3
```

Comment: sys.path.append() would work as long as the appended path contains the modules you want to import. What is your question exactly? Isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (Python 3.5+ support this syntax):

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("lib.test", "/test/lib/test.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()
```